# How to store an Image URL in database and use it in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm creating an application for uploading images to the databse and showing them in a gallery. I would like the image linking to a page. 
I just have no idea how I can call the url from the model in the view. 
Or should I make a special controller function here ?

[image: My Database]

ImageGallary.cs

```
    public partial class ImageGallery
{
    public int ImageID { get; set; }
    public int ImageSize { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public string ImageURL { get; set; }

    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please select an image file")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

Gallery.cshtml

```
    @model List <JensGoesASP.ImageGallery>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Gallery";
}

<h2>Films</h2>

@* Hier komen de geuploade images *@
<table class="table">
    @{
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i += 4)
        {
            j = i;
            @* Dit laat 4 images per rij zien *@
            <tr>
                @while (j < i + 2 && j < Model.Count())
                {
                    <td>
                        <img src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(Model[j].ImageData,0,Model[j].ImageData.Length)" style="padding-top:30px;" />
                        <a href="THE URL">Button</a> @*Here i want to get the url from the database*@
                </td>
                    j++;
                }

                </tr>
        }
    }

</table>
```

Greetz

Comment: A few suggestions: (1) don't use a table to layout your gallery, it has significant limitations. (2) don't embed your image data in the page, instead create a controller action which responds to an http request with the image data and set the src to invoke the action with an appropriate id. (3) you've already shown how to write the `ImageData` property to the page; use the same approach for writing the `ImageUrl` property for the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this code in your page.If your picture has been stored before , it shows your pics.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                <div>
                    <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageURL)" />
                </div>
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most applications will not store the image itself in the database. It adds an entire level of complication, without any obvious advantages. That would make your `ImageData` column obsolete in your example.

Rather upload the images to a particular directory on your server, via FTP or another method.

In your database, you would just store the filename, or the path and the filename, depending on your setup.

And then you would refer to the images with something like the @Ali posted.

```
<img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageURL)" />
```